# I created an htaccess file but it seems that caused POST to stop working, what can I do?

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I created the .htaccess file but apparently, it made $_POST stop working and now when I click on the button, it seems that $_POST is not receiving anything, what can I do?

Before creating the .htaccess file, it worked fine but now it doesn't

```
if(isset($_POST['login'])) {

    Connection::open_connection();

   $validator = new LoginValidator($_POST['email'],$_POST['password'],Connection::get_connection());

    if($validator -> get_error() === '' && 
        !is_null($validator -> get_user())){
        //login
        SessionControl::login(
            $validator -> get_user() -> get_id(),
            $validator -> get_user() -> get_name());
        Redirection::redirect(SERVER);
    }

    Connection::close_connection();
}
```

$_POST receives this from the html:

`<button class="login" type="submit" name="login" id="login">login</button>`

and .htaccess is this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f


RewriteRule ^.*$ ./index.php
```

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce this - what is the action in your form? What OS are you using?